# Maven, how to trigger install of parent from child module? (command prompt)

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

This is more of aesthetic question since I want to make my life easier. I have maven project structure like this:

foo-project (parent)

- foo-business (child-module)
- foo-dao  (child-module)
- foo-app  (child-module)

I run my maven commands from command prompt, I want to trigger install of all project from maven module, meaning if I am in module dir I want to trigger install from there and not to navigate to parent pom dir.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you *really* want to make your life easier, separate your parent project (i.e. the one where you put common settings for your other projects) from your aggregator project (i.e. the one that has your other projects as modules). At that point the sole purpose of your aggregator project will be to let you build all your projects together, so run your builds from there.

With Maven, doing as Maven likes is *always* going to make your life easier than any other option.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using Buildozer - an utility that I wrote some time ago in order to cleverly perform builds of given module, but building all "outdated" dependencies first.

It can be downloaded here: http://buildbox.sourceforge.net/buildozer/

It requires that you first *register* your modules (= create mapping between dir and GAV for each module), like this:

```
zer reg /home/pkozelka/my-common-modules /home/pkozelka/my-projects
```

or

```
cd /home/pkozelka/other-modules
zer reg .
```

then you go into any module and perform the build:

```
zcd my-server      # this is 'chdir by artifactId', with bashcompletion on Linux 
zer .              # compiles all (transitive) dependency modules and then this one
```